# SQL Alert to monitor Datafile growth

Tags: sql, alerts

I am currently trying to do the following - monitor the mdf and ndf of 2 of our largest databases [2008]
Set up alert::
SQL Perf condition alert
Data File size {KB}
DB
Alert if counter rises above value 0

However this is firing all the time - is there a better way of doing this or using a better counter ?

Thanks

Mo

Comment: More information is needed to answer your question. What specific condition would you like to trigger the alert? Data file size growth over a certain amount? Percentage of used vs. allocated space?

Comment: Hi - I want to capture any growth of the mdf and ndf's - at present these are set to 5GB autogrow. However im finding with counter set value 0 - the alert given is just showing the original filesize even without growth.  So in essence just require the alert to pick up that autogrowth has fired and hence increase in size of datafile.

Comment: Actually to be clear - if the alert shows autogrowth - great But id like it show growth of the mdf or ldf - at present i get The SQL Server performance counter 'Data File(s) Size (KB)' (instance 'xxxx_DB') of object 'MSSQL$M$$:Databases' is now above the threshold of 0.00 (the current value is 196295616.00). This is fired regularly but shows not change in the current value.

Comment: Anyone of any ideas...